# Controlling size of swf posted to Facebook with feed dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, flash, feed, facebook-opengraph

There are three ways to post a swf to facebook, in the first two I can control the size of the swf, but can't figure out how to do it with the feed dialog. Is there a way to do it?

1. Adding og:video:width and og:video:height tags to page and either entering url in status or going to old share url, can post swf up to 398x398.
2. With API posting to /me/feed adding width and height parameters can post a swf up to 398x398.
3. Using feed dialog (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) it seems there is no way to control the size, the swf always displays 398x224.

I would really like to use the feed dialog but be able to control the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never did find a way to control the size for a swf posted via the feed dialog, so I opened  bug:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/308822549198711

Answer (score 2):

3) Should be possible using the same og:video:width and og:video:height tags on the link you're sharing.

When attaching an SWF to an open graph page, the correct way to control the size of the SWF is by specifying the og:video:width and og:video:height open graph tags: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/#audiovideo

These sizes will be respected when posting this page in a status update, or when specifying it via the 'link' property when invoking the Feed Dialog or making Graph API posts to /me/feed.

Comment: Note, if this is not the case, file a bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: This doesn't work. Using the feed dialog always posts the swf at 398x224 regardless of what og:video:height and og:video:width tags are on the page. Using the share url uses the og tags, but posting with the feed dialog ignores the tags.